# Why are my django validators not importing?

Tags: python, django

I have a basic django project (`mysite`), with a single app: `my_app`.

The app has this in `models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models
from mysite.validators import global_file_validator
from .validators import local_file_validator

class Test(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(validators=[global_file_validator, local_file_validator])
```

It's defining a single `FileField` that must pass 2 validators.

One of the validators (`global_file_validator`) is more generic, so it's defined under `mysite.validators`, where multiple apps can use it. The other validator is specific to this app, so it's defined in this app, under `my_app/validators/local_file_validator.py`.

As far as I can tell, everything should work, but when I try to do a `./manage.py makemigrations`, I get this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 88, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 214, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 116, in load_disk
    migration_module = import_module(migration_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/my_app/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  File "/home/tal/test_django_app/my_app/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 20, in Migration
    ('file', models.FileField(upload_to='', validators=[mysite.validators.global_file_validator, my_app.validators.local_file_validator.local_file_validator])),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'local_file_validator'
```

The full code can be found here: https://github.com/tal-zvon/broken-django-validators

Why isn't this working? What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

From the Django shell, I can import both validators just fine:

```py
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from mysite.validators import global_file_validator
>>> from my_app.validators.local_file_validator import local_file_validator
```

Update: If I rename my function from `local_file_validator` to anything else, so that it doesn't have the same name as the module that contains it, everything appears to work fine. It almost seems like Django, with its migrations, is trying to do something tricky to import these validators, and the fact that the function has the same name as the module is confusing it. Seems very much like a bug. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Can you delete `db.sqlite3` and retry the `makemigrations` command?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM there's no `db.sqlite3` in my project folder. It hasn't been created yet. It fails immediately, before it's created.

Answer (score 0):

In your shell you are importing like so:

`from my_app.validators.local_file_validator import local_file_validator`

But in your models.py, you import:

`from .validators import local_file_validator`

They both can't be right. In models.py it would need to be:

`from .validators.local_file_validator import local_file_validator`

Comment: `my_app.validators` is a package. The package has a `local_file_validator` module with a `local_file_validator` function in it. The same package also has an `__init__.py` file which imports that function with `from .local_file_validator import local_file_validator`. So unless, I'm missing something, it CAN work both ways. In `models.py`,  in can be both `from .validators import local_file_validator` and it can also be `from .validators.local_file_validator import local_file_validator`. One is just more specific about which module within the package we're importing from.